# Not able to install lrzip

Tags: bash, pip

I have Ubuntu 20.04 (LTS) x64 and I would like to install lrzip to compress big big file.
However, I have problem :

```
apt install lrzip

root@ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-intel-fra1-01:~# ^C
root@ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-intel-fra1-01:~#
root@ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-intel-fra1-01:~# apt install lrzip
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package lrzip is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'lrzip' has no installation candidate
```

Any idea ?

Thank you

Comment: https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/20.04/ubuntu-universe-amd64/lrzip_0.631+git180528-1build1_amd64.deb.html Have you enabled the Repository? Ubuntu Universe amd64

Comment: Hi David, thank you ! It work now

Comment: Great I will make it an answer and then you can accept it for future users to see.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I enable the "Universe" repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ubuntu.pkgs.org/20.04/ubuntu-universe-amd64/… Have you enabled the Repository? Ubuntu Universe amd64?